# Oracle: getting error "table is mutating"

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "PARLAMENTO2018"."IMPIEGATO"
(
    "NOME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STIPENDIO" NUMBER, 
    "NUMDIP" NUMBER, 
    CONSTRAINT "IMPIEGATO_PK" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("NOME")
    CONSTRAINT "IMPIEGATO_DIPARTIMENTO_FK1" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("NUMDIP")
        REFERENCES "PARLAMENTO2018"."DIPARTIMENTO" ("NUMDIP")
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "PARLAMENTO2018"."DIPARTIMENTO" 
(
    "NUMDIP" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IMPIEGATO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    CONSTRAINT "DIPARTIMENTO_PK" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("NUMDIP")
    CONSTRAINT "DIPARTIMENTO_IMPIEGATO_FK1" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("IMPIEGATO")
        REFERENCES "PARLAMENTO2018"."IMPIEGATO" ("NOME")
);
```

Now, I want create a trigger which sets an employe's (impiegato) salary (salario) at the same amount of the manager's salary of own department (dipartimento)

I wrote only this part of trigger

```
create or replace trigger reimposta_stipendio
before update on impiegato
for each row 


begin

  for c in(
    select stipendio
    from impiegato
    where nome=(
      select impiegato
      FROM dipartimento
      where numdip=(
        select numdip
        from impiegato
        where nome = :new.impiegato)))

  loop
    dbms_output.put('Stipendio: '||c.stipendio);
  end loop;


  null;
end;
```

but when I this trigger is runned, the system return me an error of table mutanting

Comment: If error show up.. Please copy all error description.. It will get easier to identify what's error in your triggers..

Comment: UPDATE "PARLAMENTO2018"."IMPIEGATO" SET STIPENDIO = '11' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAUW9AAEAAANK3AAB' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '10989213'

One error saving changes to table "PARLAMENTO2018"."IMPIEGATO":
Row 2: ORA-04091: table PARLAMENTO2018.IMPIEGATO is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "PARLAMENTO2018.REIMPOSTA_STIPENDIO", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PARLAMENTO2018.REIMPOSTA_STIPENDIO'